# Abstract entity and its inheritors. How to store in a CSV "database"?

Tags: c#, csv, database-design

My program uses CSV files as database. Everything was easy when my entities were simple plain objects without inheritance. But now I have some structure I don't know how to properly store in CSV:

[image: Entities structure that I don't know how to store].

I have a base abstract class named `Employee`. And a couple of concrete classes that inherit that employee base class: `StaffEmployee` and `FreelanceEmployee` (I have more but for this question two are enough). And I have class `Timelog` that has a reference to `Employee` abstract class:

```
class TimelLog
{
    public Guid Id;
    // other props
    public Employee Employee;
}

abstract class Employee
{
    public Guid Id;
    // other common employee properties
    
    public abstract decimal CalcBill();
}

class StaffEmployee : Employee
{
    // unique properties

    public override decimal CalcBill()
    {
        // calculate bill according to business logic for this employee
    }
}

class FreelanceEmployee : Employee
{
    // unique properties
    
    public override decimal CalcBill()
    {
        // calculate bill according to business logic for this employee
    }
}
```

I can't come up with a proper way to store these entities in CSV files. I can store `Timelog` entity using this CSV structure:

```
id, date, workHours, employeeId
```

But how do I store employee entities?

1. I can keep only one employee.csv file that contains all fields for all employee types.
2. I can have a separate [some]employee.csv file for each concrete employee type.
3. I can have one file named employee.csv that contains only common properties and separate [some]employee.csv files that contain only unique properties for each employee type.

How you would store these entities in the CSV format?

Comment: You'll need some way to read the record, decide the actual employee type, then construct it. In other words a discriminator field. (I wouldn't, I'd use a proper database, even sqlite)